# List foreign keys linking to a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-keys

How can I display objects that link to an object via a ForeignKey in Django (specifically in the admin interface).  For example, if I click on an object, I'll not only see the object but also any other object that link to it.  e.g. I have a model for "Manufacturer" and another one for "Model"...the "Model" model links to "Manufacturer" via a foreign key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using inlines.

In your case, where each `Model` has a `Manufacturer` defined by a foreign key, first create an inline class for `Model`, then add it to your `ManufacturerAdmin` class.

The admin.py file for your application should look something like:

```
class ModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Model

class ManufacturerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    inlines = [
        ModelInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Manufacturer, ManufacturerAdmin)
```

The [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) contains details about possible customizations.